# What exactly does it mean to assign to strong from incompatible type?

Tags: objective-c

I am having a hard time finding an explanation of what it means to assign to __strong from incompatible type.  I'd like to understand the message instead of how to fix a specific instance.

I understand that __strong means that I will own the object.  For example:

```
info = [ADMCoreFactory newServiceInfoWithURI:[queue uri]];
```

In this case I am getting a warning that I am assigning '__strong id<ADMServiceInfo>' from incompatible type 'ADMCoreFactory *'

Does this mean that ADMCoreFactory needs to 'own' the object and my id<ADMServiceInfo> object needs to be a weak reference?

This is the method declaration from the header file:

```
+ (id<ADMServiceInfo>)newServiceInfoWithURI:(NSString *)anURI;
```

Comment: `__strong` doesn't really matters in this kind of error, what is the declared type of `info` ?

Comment: ADMServiceInfo is the type of the object info.

Comment: The error here is that you cannot assign a `ADMSCoreFactory` class to a `ADMServiceInfo` class type property/ivar.

Comment: ahah, not fully awake, did not notice the two `ADM...` classes were different. Yes @Firo's probably right.

Comment: I am a little confused because I am trying to call a public method from the ADMCoreFactory class that returns an ADMServiceInfo object

Comment: Can you post the method signature for `+newServiceInfoWithURI:`?

Comment: So the return type of `newServiceInfoWithURI:` is a `ADMServiceInfo` instance? Double check you are using the correct method because based on the error it really does not look like it. (make sure you are looking at the class method (starts with `+` not `-`)).

Comment: (id< ADMServiceInfo >)  + newServiceInfoWithURI:

Allocates and initializes ADDMServiceInfo with the given CUPS URI and a PRINTER as supposed device class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'__strong id<ADMServiceInfo>' from incompatible type 'ADMCoreFactory *'
```

This is telling you that `ADMCoreFactory` does not conform to the `ADMServiceInfo` protocol, and so you can't assign it to a variable of that type. `__strong` here is a bit of a red herring. It is technically part of the type, but it's not the important part in this case.

It is possible that you expect `+newServiceInfoWithURI:` to return some other type than `ADMCoreFactory`, in which case you have probably incorrectly declared it. Make sure there are no other warnings being issued. You should have no warnings at all in ObjC code.

Comment: I can actually run the app and use the object that I declared, is there a way to eliminate the warning?

Comment: You note that the return type is `id<ADMServiceInfo>` in your earlier comments. That should be an acceptable type. If that's the case, this warning suggests that you're not including the header file. Are you seeing other warnings (like "unknown selector")? clang will generally guess that methods starting with "new" return `instancetype`, which is what appears to be happening.

Comment: This is the only warning I have, I tried moving the info object into the header file but that didn't change anything.  I am including the header file from the CoreFactory class.

Comment: Update your question with the actual declaration line for `+newServiceInfoWithURI:` from the header. There's something strange here; it's probably a simple mistake.

Comment: This really suggests that the compiler is confused at this point about the return type of `+newServiceInfoWithURI:`. It is possible that there's a compiler bug here, but very unlikely. I would check the pre-processor output of this file (Product>Generate Output>Preprocessed File). That will show you what the compiler is seeing. Make sure that the declaration appears, along with the definition of the ADMServiceInfo protocol. Change the return type to something incorrect (`NSString*`) and see if that changes anything (it should).

Comment: What's interesting is if I don't tell it what kind of object it will be by removing the ADMServiceInfo from the declaration and just calling the object id info instead of id<ADMServiceInfo> I lose the warning and it runs fine as well.

Comment: I see both the protocol declaration and object declaration in the pre-processor output btw.